# Freeing the head node of linked list

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, malloc

If I free the head node of the linked list would it just remove the head node with other nodes still in memory or it would free the entire list and how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your linked list should be like:

```
head
+---+    +---+    +---+                               
| 1 |--->| 2 |--->| 3 |---+
+---+    +---+    +---+   |                                
                         null
```

`head` node keeps address of fist node only, if you do `free(head)`, then it will free memory of first node with value `1` **only** and other-nodes are still in memory and its valid to access them, but you should  first save address of node `2`, to access linked list (else you would have a memory leak in your code).

Do like:

```
   new_head = head->next;
   free(head);
```

Once you deallocate/free()  a memory, its Undefined behavior to access that not (address becomes invalid).

**From comment:**

1. Yes, you need a loop to free() memory for all nodes in linked-list, do something like this:

   ```
    while(head){          // while head not null
        new_head = head->next;   // first save address of next
        free(head);           // free first node
        head = new_head;      // set head to next node, not yet free
    }
   ```
2. comment-2:
   If you don't delete/free dynamically allocated memory in your program then it will remain allocated to your process till it not terminates  (remember in C we don't have Garbage collector). 
   Dynamically allocated memory has life till your program does't terminate. So if you have finished your work with allocated memory, free it explicitly.

Comment: so use a loop and remove the node one by one is the only choice I have or is there any way to remove the list in a single go.

Comment: @System_Coder ok you are looking for delete complete list, Yes you need a loop to free() memory for all nodes

Comment: Grijesh Chauhan here in the comment Dinesh says that if I call free(head) then the entire linked list would be removed.

Comment: I understood that removal node by node, how would the system respond if I only delete the head node without storing the next address in a pure C program.

Comment: @System_Coder then remains node will consume memory till your code not terminates

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan +1 for including a demonstration on freeing the list

Answer (score 1):

Freeing the head node would just free the memory allocated to the head node. The other list nodes would be retained. You have to then point head to the next member of the list. For example consider the following single linked list,

A -> B -> C -> D -> Null

After freeing the head node A, and moving the head to node B, the linked list would look like this

B -> C -> D -> Null

Answer (score 1):

Freeing the head node of the list only frees that node, *not* the rest of the list.

This is the main difference between arrays and linked lists - the memory is separated.
Here's an illustration:

```
 struct testnode {
      int a;
      int b;
      struct testnode * next;
 };
```

In an array, the memory may look like this:

```
 struct testnode test[3];

 0x............0000    &test[0] // on a typical computer
 0x............0020    &test[1]
 0x............0040    &test[2]
```

Notice how the elements in the array are all laid out right next to each other?
Freeing test will free and the *continous* memory that follows, only one call is need to free all the memory.

In a linked list, the memory may look like this:

```
 struct testnode * head;

 // after insertions

 0x............0000    head
 0x............634f    head->next 
 0x............114d    head->next->next
```

Notice how the memory is unsorted (although it may not always be *that* out of order).
And freeing `head` will only free the `head` node, leaving the rest of the memory untouched.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you free the head node of the linked list, you only mark memory that it used as "free for use". So, other nodes in memory still will be marked as "in use".

Technically, you still be able to use freed memory, but it is *undefined behavior*, so there is no guarantees that data (including pointers) still correct for use.

If you want to delete all nodes from memory, you should do it recursively (from the `next` pointer point of view).